# How to get options of drop down list using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have get options of drop down list using jquery for add and remove in dropdown list as per selection.

I have tried below code for get each option but it did not work for me. It's give object and I want html code like `<option value="1">1</option>`

```
<select id="drpdown" name="drpdown" multiple="multiple" size="15">
  <option data-parent="1" value="1">Test</option>                                       
</select>


 $('#drpdown').children().each(function() {
      if($(this).data('parent') != parent) 
      {
           values.push($(this));
           $(this).remove();
      } 
      else 
      {
         $(this).show();
      }
   });
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? For example, where are 'parent' and 'values' defined?

Comment: @MariaIoannidou I have added sample code of drop down list. See in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method in jQuery to do your code when the value of the drop down changes.

To get the html you need use the [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method with the "outerHTML" property.

Something like this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var a = $(this).children(":selected").get(0);
    $("div").text($(a).prop("outerHTML"));
});
```

I have created an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvrKw/)